# Counter components will not render to page

Tags: reactjs

The following code does not render the counter button to the page.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';


export default function App() {
  <>
    <Counter />
    <Counter />
  </>
}

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={ () => setCount(count + 1)} >
        Increment
      </button>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, this one does work with no problem. Why doesn't the first work to render the buttons to the page by creating a Counter component? Thank you.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';


export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [otherCount, setOtherCount] = useState(5)

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={ () => setCount(count + 1)} >
        Increment
      </button>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={ () => setOtherCount(otherCount + 1)} >
        Increment
      </button>
      <p>Count: {otherCount}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to `return ( <> <Counter /><Counter /> </> );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `return` a value from a **App** function. To solve this error, make sure to explicitly use a return statement .

```
export default function App() {
  return(
  <div>
    <Counter />
    <Counter />
  </div>
  )
}

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={ () => setCount(count + 1)} >
        Increment
      </button>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```